# How to compute series with different index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

For example, I have two series

```
X = pd.Series([0,3,4,0,-1,0])
Y = pd.Series([4,2,5,1,3,5])
```

And I want to generate a new series Z.

```
import pandas as pd
Z = []
for index in range(0,len(X)):
    if(X.iloc[index]!=0):
       temp = #(Do some arithmetic)
       Z.append(temp)
    elif(X.iloc[index]==0):
       temp = #(Do some arithmetic)
       Z.append(temp)
```

Due to the efficiency , is it possible don't need to use For-Loop?

Maybe like :

```
Z = Y*Y [X != 0]
Z = Y*Y*Y [X == 0]
#I know this is wrong,but I dont know how to correct it
```

I'm not familar with pandas , please tell me , tks!

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: If the logic is (if X != 0 , then Z= Y*Y),(if X==0 , then Z=Y*Y*Y)  then Z = [64,4,125,1,9,125] just like this , determine the value in X , then do different computation.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC it doesn't matter whether you add or subtract a **zero** value:

```
In [245]: (Y-X)/X.abs()
Out[245]:
0    3.000000
1   -0.333333
2    0.250000
3         inf
4    4.000000
5         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i was also confused by OP's code... ;-)

Comment: In short, I want to first determine whether the value of X is 0, and then do different operations . And I don't want use for-loop to determine the X one by one , maybe Pandas can do that?

Comment: @RickyParker, you can use “np.where()”